# Replace string Android

Tags: android

My question is a little bit different from others "Replace String".
I wonder is it possible to select part of string which starts for example with `<` and ends with other symbol `>` and then just replace that part?

For example `"<b>This</b> is test"`. `<b>` and `</b>` would be replaced.
Other example `"<p class="test">Another</p> test"`. `<p class="test">` and `</p>` would be replaced too.

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but as to how that depends on what you're writing your application in. On Stack Overflow it's always best to give some code that illustrates the nature of your problem even if it's got a big "???" part in the middle where you're not sure what to do.

Comment: Yes, you can use `replaceAll` with regex or the `indexOf` method.

Answer (score 0):

In java, best way to do so:

```
private String replaceString(String string, char start, char end, String replacer){
    Integer startInt=-1;
    Integer endInt=-1;
    String res;
    for(int i=0; i < string.lenght() : i++){
        if(string.charAt(i).equals(start)){
            startInt=i;
        }else{
            if(string.charAt(i).equals(start)){
                endInt=i;
            }
        }
    }
    if(startInt!=-1&&endInt!=-1){
        res=string.subString(0,startInt)+replacer+string.subString(endInt,string.lenght());
    }
}
```